# I want to put a different threshold to different images in the same directory, how can I do this?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to create a program to select and apply the threshold based on some X% of the highest pixel value found in that image. This goes for all images in the same directory. How to achieve this? I am using Python 3.

I tried following

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

but output is different for different images since grayscaled images are having different pixel values.

But I want to select threshold as a variable that is determined based on the highest pixel value in that particular image in a directory of all images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "X% of the highest pixel value found in that image"?

You can try otsu's binzarization method [link 1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#:%7E:text=image-,Otsu%27s%20Binarization,-In%20global%20thresholding) [link 2](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

> Otsu's method avoids having to choose a value and determines it automatically.

```py
thresh = cv.threshold(your_image, 0, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

If this does not solve your problem you may need to define a custom threshold method. That takes an input image and automatically finds the threshold. One way you can do this is by especifying the value of the treshold based on a condition, for an example if you want 60% of the brightest pixels. You can do:

```py
def some_function(img,Xpercent):# Xpercent in (0,1)
    n = np.histogram(img.flatten(), bins=256, range=(0, 255))[0]

    summ = 0
    for i in range(256):
        summ += n[i]
        if ((summ/sum(n))>Xpercent):
            break
    return i-1
```

The return of the function gives you the threshold based on the 60%.